# how to print a saved txt file in java using a printer

Tags: java

I created a text file using java and saved it using this code:

```
BufferedWriter bfw;
bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\abc.txt"));
```

Now I want to call the printer from my java code to print the file, how do I do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print text File to specific printer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097346/print-text-file-to-specific-printer-in-java)

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-print-a-text-file-with-javax.print-api.html

Comment: im not that good in java so i need a simplest way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to print to a specific printer which you select in a printdialog:

```
    JEditorPane text = new JEditorPane("file:///D:/abc.txt");
    text.print(null, null, true, null, null, false);
```

To print to the default printer without printdialog:

```
    JEditorPane text = new JEditorPane("file:///D:/abc.txt");
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    text.print(null, null, false, service, null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into an API that supports printing.

If you are using java 1.7 higher you can use this one. You can find an example inside the documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html